# Return a list of values of dictionaries inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains dictionaries, each of them have the same keys and different values,

How can I get a list of values of every dictionary in the list?

With `dictionary.values()` I can get a list of values of a dictionary but what if it is inside an array?

Is it necessary to do a for-loop to get every dictionary in the list?

This is what I want:

```
list= [{'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}, {'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}, {'a':6,'b':2,'c':3},]

all_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] # THIS IS THE ACTUAL QUESTION

values_of_a = [0,3,6]  # THIS COULD BE BETTER IF POSSIBLE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for both tasks:

```
>>> array = [{'a':0,'b':1,'c':2}, {'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}, {'a':6,'b':2,'c':3},]
>>> [y for x in array for y in x.values()]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
>>> [x['a'] for x in array]  # Assuming that all dicts have an 'a' key
[0, 3, 6]
>>>
```

Also, `array` is not technically an array.  It is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).  Arrays in Python are instances of [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array).

Comment: you are totally right, it is a list, not an array, I'll edit the question, and I think list comprehensions are the most efficient way, but dificult to understand, thank you @iCodez

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `lambda`:

```
>> b = map(lambda x: x.values(), a)
>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+ y, b)
>> [0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2]
>> map(lambda x: x['a'], a)
>> [0, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a `for` loop:

```
all_values = []
for d in array:
    all_values.extend(d.values())

values_of_a = []
for d in array:
    values_of_a.append(d["a"])
```