# How do I create a list of values of a list of dictionaries in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a list of dictionaries inside of each cell. I am trying to extract the values of the dictionary as a list in a new column of the same dataframe

My current dataframe looks like this:

```
id             tags         
1         [{'tag':'happy'},
           {'tag':'sad'},
           {'tag':'ok'}]

2         [{'tag':'ok'},
           {'tag':'angry'},
           {'tag':'mad'}]

3         [{'tag':'content'},
           {'tag':'very mad'},
           {'tag':'alright'}]
```

The dataframe I would like:

```
id           tags_new
1         ['happy', 'sad', 'ok']
2         ['ok', 'angry', 'mad']
3         ['content', 'very mad', alright']
```

I have tried a few options.

First, I tried:

[Return a list of values of dictionaries inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255810/return-a-list-of-values-of-dictionaries-inside-a-list)

```
df=["tags"] = [y for x in df["tags"] for y in x.values()]
```

...which gave me:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Second, I tried:

```
df["tags"] = [x in ["tag"] for x in df["tags"]]
```

...which returned boolean values.

Any suggestions? This seems like it needs a quick fix but it has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df = {
  1: [{'tag':'happy'},{'tag':'sad'},{'tag':'ok'}],
  2:[{'tag':'happy'},{'tag':'mad'},{'tag':'ok'}]
  }

for i in df:
  temp = []
  for j in df[i]:
    temp+=[j["tag"]]
  df[i]=temp

print(df)
```

Comment: I just tried and its giving me a "Key Error: 0" specifically for the "for j in df[i]:" line

Comment: Try again, I fixed it

Comment: Getting closer. I am getting a "Type Error: string indices must be integers" error about the "temp +=" line

Comment: Is your initial dictionary in the same format as mine?

Comment: Your's seems to be in a different format, mine is in a dataframe. Does that make a difference?